# Is it possible to group table except one column in Jquery data table?

Tags: jquery, datatables, google-visualization

I have a dynamic table which is grouping based on user selection. Here what my requirement is I should group all columns except one column and that column value should be last row value. Here below is my jquery code. Sorry for my English.

```
   if(sort == 'STORE'){
            // [0] gives store name
             grouped_tableData = google.visualization.data.group(dataTable, [0], cols);
             grouped_data = google.visualization.data.group(dataTable, [0], cols);

        }else{
            // [1] gives Date
             grouped_tableData = google.visualization.data.group(dataTable, [1], cols);
             grouped_data = google.visualization.data.group(dataTable, [1], cols);
        }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: here's a couple things to try -- 1) include column in the group by argument, use data view to move to end 2) group first then use `join` method to combine grouped table and non-grouped table

Comment: Could you please provide some reference?

Comment: not sure i follow but both methods (`group` and `join`) can be found under [Data Manipulation Methods](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#data-manipulation-methods)...